# Telling X to treat one screen as 2

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors

I have a very large screen, which I'd like X to treat as 2 screens.  That is, allow me to "maximize" a window to fill just one half, or to move a window to the other half.  How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split monitor in two](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150066/split-monitor-in-two)