# Desktop Manager compiz not working

Tags: unity, compiz, desktop-environments, window-manager

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and recently configured my desktop environment with the compizconfig-settings-manager. After some tries I reseted everything and suddenly all window top bars are away, I can't move or resize windows and the task bar is gone too.

I can run commands via tty, and tried some solutions. I deleted the compiz file in the `~/.config/` path and also tried to restart compiz or unity.
I also deleted and installed compiz without any change.

Nothing worked so far, I really need some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to reset the desktop environment, if you are using unity then do this:

```
unity --reset
```

If that fails to solve the problem, then try to reinstall unity(I’m assuming you are using unity):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

**Added:**
If that fails, try to do the following, to completely reset all changes made by Compiz:

Install dconf-tools: `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Reset Compiz and Unity: `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

Reset Unity: `setsid unity`

If that also fails, then maybe deleting the settings files might help:

```
rm  -rf ~/.compiz-1 
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1
```

Lastly, you could try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons
```

Comment: I tried it, nothing changed. When I used `unity --reset` it gave me the warning _no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to 0_ and an error it would be deprecated

Comment: Please see additional instructions  added to the answer.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you, @Tshilidzi, last commands helped me: 
`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

`unity --reset-icons`