# How can I split a vertical monitor into up and down?

Tags: 18.04, window-manager, display-manager

I have two monitors. One is horizontal and one is vertical. I like to split my vertical monitor into up and down, so that I can have two windows on it, one on the upper part and one on the lower part. How can I do this?

I know one can use (super + arrows) to send a window right or left.

Comment: Not as such possible in Gnome, unfortunately, except for manual positioning and resizing. However, you could try one of several Gnome extensions for tiling that are out there.

Comment: Or make the monitor treated as two monitors see this https://askubuntu.com/a/998435/77093

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up using shelltile. It works OK.

Comment: You can still post that as an answer! :)