# Cinnamon split desktop into separate workspaces

Tags: cinnamon

When I drag window to monitor egde while pressing CTRL (it is also possible by CTRL + Super + direction) it docks to edge. Other windows when maximized are placed in space what left.
It looks like desktop has been splited. It is very useful.
But.. It does not save configuration. It starts from 50% / 50% so I always have to resize workspace (I use about 33% / 66%).
Other problem is that if I close window, desktop is restored to initial state.

Is there way to save configuration of that feature? Or any other soft which could help me? Basically I would like to split single screen to mutliple separate workspaces (maybe wrong term as cinnamon workspaces is not a thing what I look for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution using xrandr
https://askubuntu.com/a/998435/705261

For my xrandr output

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   (...)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   (...)
HDMI-1-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   (...)
```

I wanted my second monitor split to 1/3 and 2/3 so I have script

```
xrandr --setmonitor HDMI-1-1~1 640/159x1080/268+1920+0 HDMI-1-1
xrandr --setmonitor HDMI-1-1~2 1280/318x1080/268+2560+0 none
```

that is effect. Works well :)
Both windows on screenshot below are maximized.

[image: split screen]