# How to manage to split screen in a special way

Tags: xubuntu, screen, display-resolution, split

Hard for me to explain what I need but I'm going to do my best.

I've got a stretch screen (1920x540 resolution) and a XUbuntu OS. I've got contents in 960x1080

I've managed to set 2 virtual monitors :

1 on left : 960x540
1 on right : 960x540 on a part where I need to display what is below the left screen (I don't know how to do this part).

To be clear, it's like if I wanted the cursor to disappear when I go below the left virtual screen, so that it appears to the top on right virtual screen.

Comment: So you're asking how to change the positions of the monitors relative to each other? In "display settings", just drag them around with the mouse.

Comment: I don't think so, as I've got only one physical screen (monitor).

Comment: But then what do you mean by "managed to set 2 virtuals resolutions"?

Comment: I've followed this advice to set 2 virtual monitors : https://askubuntu.com/a/998435/1222679