# Split Screen with Ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome via xrandr

Tags: 20.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, xrandr

Challenge: I am trying to split me 32:9 wide screen into two virtual monitors.

Background: While working, I need to share my screen using Microsoft Teams for Linux. Teams is not able share parts of the screen but only single windows. When sharing single windows, some parts of the shared application are not visible (such as new windows, menus, tooltips etc.). I have to share my screen so that the whole content of an application is visible. My widescreen is to big for many of my peers, so that they only see a scaled down window which makes it difficult for them to read.

I already found a part of the solution here: [Split monitor in two](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150066/split-monitor-in-two/998435#998435)

The virtual monitors are clearly there, when I follow the solution. MS Teams is able to capture it (which means, my peers only get half of my screen as expected). Now, I would like to see the result on my own screen in Gnome, too, because it helps me organizing my windows (as tiling is easier).

How to achieve, that Gnome is using the virtual monitors created via xrandr as described in the post above?

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue. I see the virtual screens, but can't make my windows to respect them. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Solution from Strachu works here in (L)Ubuntu20.04. Did divide my horizontal resolution and "size" in mm by 4 and by 3. realized that three quarter is to much, so changed to two third and one third:

DVI-I-1-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1872mm x 1053mm
   3840x2160     60.00*   50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
-->
xrandr --setmonitor DVI-I-1-1~1 2560/1248x2160/1053+0+0 DVI-I-1-1
xrandr --setmonitor DVI-I-1-1~2 1280/1249x2160/1053+2560+0 none

Maximizing a window in left two thirds and right third works perfectly