# Split Screen Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: display, screen, split

I am new t the Linux Ubuntu world. I am try to get two screens on my 29 wide lg monitor.
the split screens would be use to work on two different projects. Both need to have the menu bar to the left. I have tried some other suggestion, but none worked.

if you have an idea of how to go about this, i would greatly appreciate your help.
i am also learning the Ubuntu interface and terminology. so if you use something that is new terminology please explain.

thank you for your help.
User1695106

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly supported. One monitor displays a single workspace. That said, [something can be done](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398508/split-a-widescreen-monitor-in-two?rq=1) using hacks, and provided you use the venerable Xorg display driver rather than Wayland, the default on Ubuntu 22.04.

In Ubuntu, you can have different workspaces, and decide which one is displayed on a monitor. Is it not a better option to have two separate projects on two different workspaces?

Alternatively, just place windows related to one project on one half, those related on the other on the other half.

If each project is a single window (for example browser windows with tabs, a terminal with tmux, ...) then you can easily tile them left or right by dragging them on the side, or using keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd>)

Comment: I thank you for your help. I am totally new to Linux ubuntu, I guessing a steep learning cure.  Ps I am 70 yrs old